# Flickering components when animating the maxHeight of the ScrollView (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native

I have To-Do list elements which can expand and collapse by pressing the associated button.

[image: Android Emulator. Same behavior on my physical Android device]

By pressing on the EXPAND Button the height of the Animated ScrollView gets adjusted. From 0 to 100 when expanding and from 100 to 0 when collapsing. When we expand two list-objects at the same time, the screen begins to flicker.

Here the code of one single todo-element (it is abbreviated, means the DONE button is not in it):

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, memo } from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, View, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import longText from '../data/data';

const ListObject = (props) => {
    
    //Object Expand and Collapse feature
    const expandValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const [expandState, setExpand] = useState(false);

    const expandAnimation = () => {
        Animated.timing(expandValue, {toValue: 100, duration: 1000, useNativeDriver: false}).start();
        setExpand(true);
    }
    
    const collapseAnimation = () => {
        Animated.timing(expandValue, {toValue: 0, duration: 1000, useNativeDriver: false}).start();
        setExpand(false);
    }


    return (
        <View style={{ margin: props.margin }}>
            <View style={{
               flexDirection: 'row',
               backgroundColor: 'grey',
               borderRadius: 10, 
            }}>

                <Button title='EXPAND' style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                }}
                onPress={ expandState ? collapseAnimation : expandAnimation }
                />
            </View>

            <Animated.ScrollView style={{ 
                flex: 1,
                paddingHorizontal: 40,
                backgroundColor: 'grey',
                borderRadius: 10,
                maxHeight: expandValue
             }}>
                <Text>{ props.text }</Text>              
            </Animated.ScrollView>

        </View>
    );


}


export default memo(ListObject);
```

Here is the code for the App. To make a collection of all todo-elements, I map over a list and assign a key to each element:

```js
mport React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import longText from './src/data/data';
import ListObject from './src/components/list-object'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeContainer: {
    flex: 1.2
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flex: 0.2,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  headerFont: {
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1 
  }
});


const App = () => {


    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) => 
      <ListObject key={number.toString()} margin={10} headerText='I am the header of the to-do element' text={longText} />
    )



  return (

    <SafeAreaView style={ styles.safeContainer } >
      
      <View style={ styles.headerContainer }>
          <Text style={ [styles.headerFont] }>LIST MAKER</Text>
      </View>

      <ScrollView style={ styles.scrollContainer }>

      {listItems}

      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  
  
  );

};

export default App;
```

I expected no flickering. The flickering appears also on my physical Android device. I have searched for similar problems and checked other libraries how they implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake by myself, it's a beginner's mistake.

Instead of managing the state of the component in the component itself, I had to lift the state up to the parent.

Here the link to the [ReactJS](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components) learning doc.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use [react-native-collapsible](https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible)

```
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

const [activeSections, setActiveSessions] = useState([])

const _updateSections = (activeSections) => {
    setActiveSessions(activeSections.includes(undefined) ? [] : activeSections)
  }

<Accordion
        sections={data}
        activeSections={activeSections}
        duration={400}
        renderHeader={_renderHeader}
        renderContent={_renderContent}
        onChange={_updateSections}
        touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
        renderAsFlatList={true}
        expandMultiple={true}
      />
```

For better performance and a smooth experience use this one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to implement it by myself. I started with react a week ago and would like to understand the details.

Comment: You can find whole example here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/master/Example/App.js